# Multiple bluetooth adapters connected with specific bluetooth devices

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, devices, input-devices, adapter

I have connected two bluetooth adapters into ubuntu 14.04 (hci0 and hci1)

[adapters connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOAXS.png)

and I have two different bluetooth devices

[devices connected here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4aoR.png)

I'm trying to connect one adapter with one device in a specific and separate way, like hci0 with device 0 (HC05) and hci1 with device 1 (bluetooth_v3).

I have tried these commands:

```
sudo rfcomm connect hci0 '98:D3:31:FD:5B:6E' 0
```

and

```
sudo rfcomm connect hci1 '20:14:05:16:23:73' 1
```

However, I get this error: `Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Invalid argument.`

Can someone help me?

I would eventually like to scale it up by having each adapter connected to 6 devices each.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Did you pair the devices first?

Comment: have you looked into `bluetoothctl`?